# USB Mouse not working on Samsung ChromeBook 3

Tags: usb, mouse, chrome-os, chrome-book, samsung

Samsung ChromeBook 3 on Chrome OS beta channel. Developer mode is enabled.

USB Keyboards work OK, but USB Mouse isn't working. (I only have one to test but it works ok on other linux PC)

The peripheral seems to be correctly identified but, this is the relevant dmesg:

```
[47203.581103] usb 1-2: new low-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[47203.749877] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=09da, idProduct=000a
[47203.749899] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[47203.749912] usb 1-2: Product: PS/2+USB Mouse
[47203.749921] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: A4Tech
[47203.750569] usb 1-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[47203.756104] platform vpd: Driver vpd requests probe deferral
[47203.756157] platform vpd: Driver vpd requests probe deferral
```

Comment: Your question looks like a regression/bug to me, why don't you report it directly to the Chrome developers in their bug tracker? That would make everyone's life easier. You get accurate information from the people that have sufficient knowledge about the platform and the developers get direct feedback. Just look at some of the Chromebook related answers here and you know that you'd want a second opinion.